# Which H.265 encoder supports main444-16-stillpicture?

Tags: hevc, video-codecs, libx265

Does anyone know an encoder which supports the "main444-16-stillpicture" profile (for 16 bits bit-depth images) ?

I know that VideoLAN's x265 encoder does not support it!

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @aergistal, I work in the field of video codec, I can assure you this much at this point of time there are no encoders that would be developed wrt 16 bit depth. I have seen many open source encoders as well as some licensed ones as well, however, the maximum bit depth supported is 12. I am sure there are some companies are working though there is no rising market demand for it.

Comment: @Harrisson Thanks, I know. I'm not the asker, I just edited his question :) There's a lib for BPG but they're using x265 and JCTVC, so max 12 as you said.